# jQuery, onclick and disabled select

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a problem trying to get an onclick event to work consistently between different browsers, when that onclick is covering a disabled `<select>` (using jQuery 1.9.1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Onclick</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/RiO/Common/js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickme(s)
            {
                alert ("Hello! " + s);
            }

            function init()
            {
                $('#ie10').each(function() {
                    var ele = $(this);
                    onclicker = "clickme('" + ele.attr('id') + "');";
                    ele.wrap('<span onclick="' + onclicker + '">');
                });

                $('#ff').each(function() {
                    var ele = $(this);
                    ele.wrap('<span style="position:relative">');
                    ele.after($('<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;"></div>').on('click', function() { return clickme(ele.attr('id')); }));
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body onload="init();">
        IE8/IE10 clickable: <span onclick="clickme('boo!');"><select id="ie8" disabled="true">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
        </select></span>
        <br />
        IE10 clickable: <select id="ie10" disabled="true">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        Everything else clickable: <select id="ff" name="ff" disabled="true">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

In essence, the first binding only works in IE10, the second one in Firefox, Chrome, and everything else. Ideally I need it working back to IE8 - the only way I've found to bind IE8 is to hardcode the span - trying to insert it with jQuery fails.

However IE10 and FF/Chrome also work differently in that overlaying a  doesn't work in IE at all - it's as if the select takes precedence (and as it's disabled it swallows any clicks).

I've also tried, using document.on() as follows:

```
$(document).on ('click', '.clicker', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return clickme("moo");
});

$('ie').wrap ('<span class="clicker">');
```

...which again works for IE10 and FF (for the respective span/overlaying div), but also fails to work in IE8.

As this is code that generated dynamically, I don't want to end up having to sniff the user-agent in the underlying business logic to create the correct code - but at the moment I can't see what else to do. Thoughts?

**Update:**
IE mostly appears to have problems binding events to dynamically added elements. If I bind an event to an existing element (i.e., if I always wrap all selects in a , then `$(span).on('click', ...)` works. So there's a possible route forward there, however I still would prefer the same solution for both IE and FF to save code duplication (and remove some complexity from the code), although I'm guessing this isn't practical.

It's also worth noting that it's only selects. If select is replaced with a disabled `input` textbox, then I have more reliable behaviour between browsers: i.e., wrapping the element in a `<span>` is all that's needed for it to work between browsers

Comment: jquery version please !

Comment: Sorry, added to question prologue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're creating all the spans around the option elements. 
Isn't it easier to use jQuery's onChange event?

http://jsfiddle.net/rsfxR/1/

```
$(document).on('change', '.change_selectbox',function() {
    alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Updated reply: 
[jsfiddle.net/rsfxR/2](http://jsfiddle.net/rsfxR/2)

Activate the selectboxes on click:

```
$('#myform *').filter(':input').each(function(){        
    if($(this).attr('disabled') == "disabled"){
        $(this).wrap("<span class='inactive'></span>"); 
    };
});

$(document).on('click', '.inactive', function(){
    $(this).children("select").prop('disabled',false);

    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
});
```

Update #2: it seems that firefox wants an extra `<div>` in the HTML, so this should be complete:

```
    $('#ie10').each(function() {
        var ele = $(this);
        ele.wrap ('<span class="clicker"></span>');
        ele.after ('<div></div>');
    });
```

where the `<div>` has the following CSS:

```
    span.clicker > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: These are disabled selects, therefore there is no change event. The business rule requires click-to-activate for the field, so I need to be able to detect the click so I can enable the field. As it stands, different browsers require different implementations, which is a right pain to have to deal with.

The span is needed to position an absolute div over the select that captures the onclick (for FF/Chrome/etc); the div is positioned and sized to the span.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rsfxR/2/  Not sure about the positioning though.

Comment: Yes, exactly that, although I can't test it in IE8 as jsfiddle doesn't work with IE8. However, pulling your fiddle into a single HTML page it doesn't appear to work in Chrome (whilst your fiddle does)? I can't see what you're doing vs. what I'm doing. I'm loathed to update the question (due to length), so see what I've thrown up to pastebin at http://pastebin.com/QJYKrUKS ... I'm guessing I've missed something obvious but I'm suffering code-blindness staring at this problem.

Comment: I uploaded my code (temporarily) to: http://www.zwoop.be/bb/ It seems to work in both Chrome and IE8 for me. It also works in IE7.

Comment: Okay, I now have working code - still not quite sure how my code differed, but I've poked it into working based on this. One this is that I see that it's the CSS you've included that's critical to making this work cross-browser without resorting to different solutions: it's that magic I was missing (although it really shouldn't be needed - c'est la vie).

Comment: Perhaps that could have been it, I have put a -1 z-index on the disabled select to make the span clickable on top.

Comment: Currently *not* working in firefox -- but IE8/IE10/Chrome all okay? Both your code on zwoop and mine.

Comment: Is the Javascript broken? I have a feeling that it might be related to the CSS Z-index, but I'm currently unable to use Firefox at the office.

Comment: I've had to add a 'div' into the mix - don't ask me why, but it works. I'll be updating your answer to include this so there is a complete answer that I can green-tick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, glad that it worked out for you. I think I might have messed up something with the CSS positioning and Z-index. I'm pretty sure that it's not a JS error anyhow. I'll be removing my www.zwoop.be/bb code in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

u said u tried the `on` function?
but ur function seems to be wrong
would be like this:

```
$('#ie10').on('click', function() {
    clickme('User');
}
```

Comment: The `on` tried is the document-level `on` which takes a CSS class (thus creating a delegated event handler -- see http://api.jquery.com/on/ ). This was tried as binding `click` to a dynamically added element wasn't working in IE.

Comment: which IE do you mean? JQuery 1.7+ should support it

Comment: i often use  `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {// el.unbind.on('click', function(){//do stuff})});`

Answer (score 0):

Would it be suitable to populate it when the onchange event is triggered like that :

Javascript :

```
function populate(select)
{
    var option1=document.createElement("option");
    option1.text="One";
    var option2=document.createElement("option");
    option2.text="Two";
    var option3=document.createElement("option");
    option3.text="Three";
    select.options[0] = null;
    select.options.add(option1, null);
    select.options.add(option2, null);
    select.options.add(option3, null);
}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
Populated once clicked : 
<select id="sel1" name="sel1" onmousedown="populate(this)">
    <option>Disabled - Click to enable</option>
</select>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rtd9/